# Numpy exp() not callable

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror, exp

If I use 2 np arrays as x,y input into the following expression...

```
out = np.exp(3(x-4)-0.0001*y)
```

...I get "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

If I use the same as function and call this function with a curve fit I get a similiar error:

```
def func(X, a, b):
    x,y = X
    return np.exp(a(x-4)-b*y)
```

Here I get:'numpy.float64' object is not callable

What am I doing wrong? It's working with others type of functions that don't use exp.

Comment: What do you think `3(x-4)` means in Python?

Comment: ohhhh, I missed that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
out = np.exp(3(x-4)-0.0001*y)
```

The problem in this expression is that the np.exp() function takes one argument but you passed 2. I don't know this is the best solution but instead of this you can try:

```
operations = 3*(x-4) - (0.0001*y)
out = np.exp(operations)
```

Comment: Thank you, 2 arguments work fine. The problem was the missing "*" after the 3.